# Wamp server needs me to start mysqld.exe manually

Tags: mysql, windows-10, wampserver

I'm using Wampserver 3.1.7 64bit which came with MySQL version 5.7.24. 
I wanted to upgrade to a version of MySQL greater than 8. I did manage to install the new version which does work. However, I need to start mysqld.exe manually in order for this to happen.
Although the wampserver icon does not go green (stays orange) and says only 2 of 3 services started, mySQL (the third service) does infact work.

```
***** Test which uses port 3306 *****

===== Tested by command netstat filtered on port 3306 =====


Test for TCP
Your port 3306 is used by a processus with PID = 4708
The processus of PID 4708 is 'mysqld.exe' Session: Console
The service of PID 4708 for 'mysqld.exe' is 'N/A'
*** ERROR *** This service IS NOT from Wampserver - Should be: 'wampmysqld64' or 'wampmariadb64'

Test for TCPv6
Your port 3306 is used by a processus with PID = 4708
The processus of PID 4708 is 'mysqld.exe' Session: Console
The service of PID 4708 for 'mysqld.exe' is 'N/A'
*** ERROR *** This service IS NOT from Wampserver - Should be: 'wampmysqld64' or 'wampmariadb64'
```

Could you advise how I can get wamp to start mysql service automatically? i.e. without me having to first load the mysqld.exe service manually, which wamp does not recognize. many thanks

Edit: This might be able to assist, I've also noticed that when I try to start the wampmsqld64 service from the wamp menu within the system tray, under Service administration -> Start/Resume service. I get the following error output to wamps mysql error logs

```
2020-04-03T10:22:45.451115Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-000077] [Server] c:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql8.0.19\bin\mysqld.exe: Error while setting value 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER' to 'sql_mode'.
2020-04-03T10:22:45.452532Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2020-04-03T10:22:45.452866Z 0 [Note] [MY-010120] [Server] Binlog end
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have an instance of mysql server (or something else) started on port 3306.

Check in Task Manager what is using it, and remove app which is using this port, or change initial port in Wamp....

edit: i'm not sure if it is posible to use other versions of software than ones which are bundled in wamp.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I have already tried starting mysql on port 3308 and still get the same error. If I start mysqld manually once again it will work, however the problem remains that wamp cannot start the daemon automatically. I'd like to know how to get wamp to start it's own service wampmysqld64 or even mysqld automatically? many thanks

Comment: @mozzy69 in wamp my.ini file, change port of wamp mysql service, restart everything, and is should work...

Comment: hi thanks for the answer just fyi you can also change the port number of wamp's mysql service through the wamp menu within the system tray. I've done both as you can see here 
; The MySQL server
[wampmysqld64]
;skip-grant-tables
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
port = 3308
But this unfortunately does not solve the issue. I don't think the issue is related to a port conflict as much as wamp unable to recognize that mysqld and wampmysqld64 are the same service essentially

Comment: yes I agree, but the question remains how to get wamp to recognise that?